# Need shell script to auto login to remote server

Tags: shell, unix, autologin

I have 10 Linux servers.
To connect to server every time I have to execute the ssh command to login.
I need one single shell script to login to a remote server.
e.g if server is host name is `testhost.com`, user is `user1` and pass `password`
when I give the user name `user1` in terminal, it should automatically execute the shell script and logged in to remote server for the user `user1`

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. We will gladly help you with your problems, but you cannot just expect other people to code stuff for you. Rather, edit your question and tell us what you have already tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Hi i know this is an old question but here is a way to do it follow the link above from the @nick hartung  then after that since you have 10 servers you call each server by name so say 'server1' or any name you like but for this example ill name one of the servers 'server1' also remember to change the port from 22 to something else eg 22277 so create a script and name it server1 and the put this in it

```
#!/bash/bin
ssh username@hostname -p22277
```

then move the script to user bin

```
$ sudo chmod 600 server1
$ sudo mv server1 /usr/bin/
```

then now u can just login to the remote host like this

```
$ server1
```

the you will be automatically logged in.

Comment: An alternative to storing the script in /usr/bin would be to store it somewhere in your local directory structure and create an alias, which executes it, called "server1"

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script that will take a username as a parameter and ssh to the correct host based on that. A quick example:

```
if [ "$1" == "username" ]; then
   ssh username@hostname
fi
if [ "$1" == "username2" ]; then
...
```

However, the ssh command doesn't have a built in way to provide a password AFAIK. You shouldn't be storing your passwords in a script anyway. The way to get around this is to set up automatic authentication by creating a key pair using ssh-keygen. [Here](http://www.rebol.com/docs/ssh-auto-login.html) is a link that will show you how to set this up.